# How can I change content of multiple divs based on if statement in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: php, mysql

How can I use jascript to change the content of multiple divs that are based on a mysql result

This is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT userid, username FROM tbl_user";
$myResult = mysql_query ($sql); 
$num=mysql_numrows($myResult);
$i=0;

while ($i < $num) 
{
?>
<div id="userName"><?php echo mysql_result($myResult,$i,"username"); ?></div>
<div id="onlineStatus"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        jqcc.cometchat.getUser('<?php echo mysql_result($myResult,$i,"userid"); ?>','checkstatus');
   }
   function checkstatus(data) {
       console.log(data); // To see output using Firebug
       if (data.s == 'available') {
           document.getElementById("onlineStatus").innerHTML="Online";
       }
       else
       {
           document.getElementById("onlineStatus").innerHTML="Offline";
       }
   }                    
</script>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

This only changes the first "onlineStatus" div to Online or Offline. How can I change all the "onlineStatus" divs accordingly?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you had bought this then you should be asking the support team of the app,they'll help better

Comment: Have you tried (heard of) ajax? Because with you current code, the data from the server will be loaded once and that's it.

Comment: Yes I have heard of ajax, but I just want the data to load one off. My problem is how to change the text in onlineStatus div for every occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to assgin the php mysql_result($myResult,$i,"userid") to a variable and then check it's type.. (it's an array, a string, it's null....) if it's a common string and can be printed with an echo you should be able to stamp it inside the js code:

```
<?php $myVar = mysql_result($myResult,$i,"userid"); ?>
jqcc.cometchat.getUser('<?php echo $myVar; ?>','checkstatus');
```